# Can I power a device with a power supply that has a higher current rating?

Tags: power-supply, current, current-limiting, high-current

I have a device with an input rating of 23 to 56V DC with a maximum current of 0.5 amperes. Is it possible to supply this device with a power supply with an output rating of 48V DC with 1.0 ampere?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: All caps is generally viewed as yelling and/or impolite.

Comment: Let's talk about inrush current

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be fine. Your load will determine how much current it needs. Not because your power supply can provide 1A max means that your load will constantly draw that much current. The 1A is your supply's max current that can be drawn.

Now, you don't want to over voltage your load, because that can make the load pull more current than its max rating of 0.5 amps.